# How does the Cryo Cannon's ‘Fragile’ upgrade work?

Tags: deep-rock-galactic

The Cryo Cannon's ‘Fragile’ upgrade is described as "frozen targets can spontaneously shatter".

The way in which it is worded suggests that there is a random chance for frozen targets to shatter. What is this chance and does this chance depend on the type of enemy being frozen?

[image: Cryo Cannon's ‘Fragile’ upgrade]

Answer (score 3):

According to [this video](https://youtu.be/UdpJiAqG2sk), the  Fragile upgrade has a 50% chance on freeze to shatter regular enemies that are under 85% health, with an unknown chance to shatter Special Enemies that are below 100 Health

Edit: On personal testing, it seems like the chance is only calculated one time as soon as the enemy is frozen. Grunts usually lose ~15% of their health as you freeze them, so I've found this upgrade to be beneficial mostly when attacking large numbers of swarmers or grunts.